# How to Apply Shadow to BottomAppBar?

Tags: android, shadow, floating-action-button, android-bottomappbar

I want bellow type of shadow with Floating Action Button,
but because of White background color, my Shape with floating action but not show.
So, how can I apply shadow to BottomAppBar

My requirement is [requirement]

[image]

but my output is

[image]

Comment: please post your code

Comment: if color is the only issue then you can give different color to the shadow line like gray or someother

Comment: no other colors,My requirement is only white background with shadow,so please give suggestion for that if you have.